# TSLint , enforce spacing between brackets in import statements

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

Which rule do I need to apply to enforce spaces between curly brackets in the import statements?

i.e

Instead of :

```
import {IPostService} from './api/IPostService';
```

I want:

```
import { IPostService } from './api/IPostService';
```

Comment: Would suggest having a look at [Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) then you will not need any more rules for these kind of things :)

Comment: Add bracketSpacing to true in visual code .prettierrc or add --bracket-spacing if you are using prittier NPM package.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
"whitespace": [true, "check-module"]
```

**check-module** - checks for whitespace in import & export statements.

Comment: For the documentation: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/whitespace/